# Why Android VPN applications do not use BIND_VPN_SERVICE?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, openvpn

I am analyzing Android VPN applications(e.g., Hola**) permissions usage. It is stated, as far as Google official manual(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), that a VPN application must use BIND_VPN_SERVICE permission but Hola does not stat it in its Manifest file. I want to know why it does not use this permission and how it (or in general VPN apps) offers VPN service?

** Hola's permissions in Manifest file:

- android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
- android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
- android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.GET_TASKS
- android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
- android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
- android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
- com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
- org.hola.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
- com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
- com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
- android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know why it does not use this permission

Because it does not need the permission, which is good because it cannot hold the permission. `BIND_VPN_SERVICE` is a `signature`-level permission.

Quoting [the documentation for `BIND_VPN_SERVICE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_VPN_SERVICE), with emphasis added:

> Must be **required** by a VpnService, to ensure that only the system can bind to it.

Where you should find `BIND_VPN_SERVICE` in an app's manifest is *not* in a `<uses-permission>` element, but rather in an `android:permission` attribute on a `<service>` element for the `VpnService` implementation. The app is *defending* a component using a permission, not *using* the permission to talk to other apps.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, for details one could also refer to [OpenConnect](https://github.com/cernekee/ics-openconnect/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) where `BIND_VPN_SERVICE` is request in `<service>` tag i.e., <service
            android:name="app.openconnect.core.OpenVpnService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>